# R tm document names missing

Tags: r, tm

Using R{tm} package, i create a corpus, per usual:

`mycorpus <- Corpus(DirSource(folder,pattern="txt"))`

Please note I am not using an encoding variable. The `summary (mycorpus)` shows document names listed. However after a series of tm_map transforms:

`(content_transformer(tolower),content_transformer(removeWords), stopwords("SMART"),stripWhitespace)`
ending with `mycorpus<- tm_map(mycorpus, PlainTextDocument)` and `mydtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(mycorpus, control = list(...))`

I get an error with `inspect(mydtm[1:10, intersect(colnames(dtm), 'toyota')])` to get my variable of choice: 

              `Terms
Docs           toyota
  character(0)       0
  character(0)       0
  character(0)       0
  character(0)       0
  character(0)       1
  character(0)       0
  character(0)       0
  character(0)       0
  character(0)       1
  character(0)       0`

The file names (doc ids) have disappeared. Any idea what could be causing this error? more importantly, how do i reinstate the document names? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Code below will work for single file.  You likely could use something like list.files to read all files in the directory.
First, I would wrap the cleaning functions in a custom function.  Note the order matters and you have to use `content_transformer` if the function is not from `tm`.

```
clean.corpus<-function(corpus){
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, custom.stopwords)
  return(corpus)
}
```

Then concatenate English words with custom words.  This is passed as the last part of the custom function above.

```
custom.stopwords <- c(stopwords('english'), 'lol', 'smh')

doc<-read.csv('coffee.csv', header=TRUE)
```

The CSV is a data frame with a column of tweets in a text document and another column with an ID for each tweet.  The file from my workshop with this file is [here](https://github.com/diegonogare/DataScience/tree/master/Text%20Mining).
The csv file is now in memory so next step is to read it in tabular fashion with a specific mapping when making a corpus.  Here the content is in a column called text and the unique ID is in a column name "id".

```
custom.reader <- readTabular(mapping=list(content="text", id="id"))
corpus <- VCorpus(DataframeSource(doc),  readerControl=list(reader=custom.reader))
corpus<-clean.corpus(corpus)
```

The corpus creation uses the `readerControl` and then once done you can apply the pre-processing steps.  Without the reader control the package assigns the 0 character as the name.

The corpus content of document 1 can be accessed here

```
corpus[[1]][1]
```

You can review the corpus meta data for the first document with this code

```
corpus[[1]][2]
```

So I think you are needing to use `readTabular` and `readerControl` in your corpus construction no matter the source.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I realized that it was due to *tolower*. *tolower*, unlike *removeNumbers*, *removePunctuation*, *removeWords*, *stemDocument*, *stripWhitespace* are not tranformations defined in the *tm* package. To get a list of transformations defined in the tm package that can be directly applied to a corpus, type:

```
getTransformations()
[1] “removeNumbers” “removePunctuation” “removeWords” “stemDocument” “stripWhitespace”
```

Thus, in order to use *tolower* it first must make a transformation for *tolower* for it to handle corpus objects properly.

```
docs <- tm_map(docs,content_transformer(tolower))
```

The above line of code should stop the files from being renamed to *character(0)*

The same trick can be applied to any R function to work with corpuses. For example for gsub, the following syntax applies:

```
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(gsub), pattern = “internt”, replacement = “internet”)
```